# Parent scrolling on IFrame focus

Tags: javascript, html, events, iframe, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet embeded in my html page. The problem is that whenever I click spreadsheet cell, the parent page scrolls up to the top, thereby making it difficult to work with the embedded spreadsheet.

Steps to reproduce - 
1. Let google spreadsheet load in the iframe.
2. click somewhere in the parent page
3. click on any cell of the google spreadhseet.
4. The parent page scrolls up to the top of the page.

I faced this in FF, Chrome. In IE9, I was not able to load the spreadsheet - was denied by the browser.

Can any one give some pointers?